# Multiple jMeter scripts for Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins

I'm interested is it possible using Jenkins+Performance plugin to run more than one .jmx (jMeter) files.
I'm using SVN repository where I keep my jMeter scripts. But problem is I can add only one jmx file to repo. I want add more than one, but Jenkins runs only first one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Ant to do this in Jenkins.

Note the "testplans" element in the following build.xml snippet:

```
<jmeter>
    jmeterhome="c:\jakarta-jmeter-1.8.1"
    resultlog="${basedir}/loadtests/JMeterResults.jtl">
    <testplans dir="${basedir}/loadtests" includes="*.jmx"/>
</jmeter>
```

More info here: http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/